# Initailize a function only once in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a custom code to fire my Live chat bot instance if a user visits a particular URL.

```
if(location.hash.indexOf("#/financial-bills")>-1){
return true;
```

The issue is the chats are repeating if I go to child URLs e.g #/financial-bills/summary
My chat code is below:

```
 var initESW = function(gslbBaseURL) {
 embedded_svc.init(
        'https://example.com',
        'https://example/ChatBot',
        gslbBaseURL,
        '00D4C00000019Iy',
        'Support_Only',
        {
        baseLiveAgentContentURL: 'https://c.la2-c1cs.com/content',
        deploymentId: '5721E',
        buttonId: '5731E',
        baseLiveAgentURL: 'https://d.la2-c1cs.com/chat',
        eswLiveAgentDevName: 'EmbeddedServiceLiveAgent_Parent0200EAA_1754b2de11b',
        isOfflineSupportEnabled: false
        }
    );
    };



if (!window.embedded_svc) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('src', 'https://example/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js');
        s.onload = function() {
        initESW(null);
   };
document.body.appendChild(s);
 } else {
initESW('https://service.force.com');
}
```

[image: Repeating Chats]

My issue is I want the chat function to initialize only once. As I beleive it is causing the chats to repeat. I have tried removing the chat script based on URL change event but its not working for me.

```
 script.id = "test";
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
    (elem=document.getElementById("test")).parentNode.removeChild(elem)
    });
```

Comment: Why not set a temporary `cookie` for this? When the function is called once, just set the cookie and then make a check on all subsequent calls. If it's set, don't call the function.

Comment: Actually the the events are set in other tool called Adobe Exp manager. I can only modify the custom code which I have posted. If you have a way using cookie. Can you provide an example. I can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary session cookie to check if the chat was initialized once or not. If not just initialize the chat and set the `cookie`.

```js
function setCookie(cname,cvalue) {
  document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue;
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}


if(!getCookie('chatInitialized')){
  initChat();
  setCookie('chatInitialized', true);
}
```

Comment: I guess thats not the issue. As everytime I swtich state in my app. A new script tag is created which causes the chats to repeat

Comment: Should I also add `window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
(elem=document.getElementById("test")).parentNode.removeChild(elem)
});`

Comment: Even if the script tag is injected twice, the cookie shall remain persistent. Hence handling your needs without the `window.addEventListener`

Comment: Correct. But even after the cookie the chats are repeating. I don't know why. The cookie is present . Can't debug also :(

Comment: Why not? You can put `console.log('')` tags to see why it's going within the `if` condition even when the cookie is present in your code above. You can then check the output of your `console.log`s in your browser console.

Comment: So I saw whats the issue. The code is correct. Actually the script is multiplying because of the History change default event in Adobe exp. manager https://helpx.adobe.com/nz/dtm/kb/How_to_use_DTM_for_Single_Page_Apps.html

Comment: I will have to wrte a custom event for that.